# How can I make a diamond of zeroes in a matrix of any size?

Tags: matlab

I have a  square Matrix N x M, odd dimensions, and I want to put a diamond of zeroes, for example, for a 5 x 5 matrix:

```
1 3 2 4 2
5 7 8 9 5
3 2 4 6 3 
6 8 2 1 3 
3 3 3 3 3
```

Is transform to:

```
1 3 0 4 2 
5 0 8 0 5 
0 2 4 6 0 
6 0 2 0 3
3 3 0 3 3
```

How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: There are many ways. Why don't you show us your current approach and we'll see if we can improve on it.

Comment: show us your current (inefficient) way

Comment: Be sure to test it out with an even-numbered matrix, as well....

Answer (score 2):

I'll bite, here is one approach:

```
% NxN matrix
N = 5;
assert(N>1 && mod(N,2)==1);
A = magic(N);

% diamond mask
N2 = fix(N/2);
[I,J] = meshgrid(-N2:N2);
mask = (abs(I) + abs(J)) == N2;

% fill with zeros
A(mask) = 0;
```

The result:

```
>> A
A =
    17    24     0     8    15
    23     0     7     0    16
     0     6    13    20     0
    10     0    19     0     3
    11    18     0     2     9
```

Comment: Very nice! And with only 4 LOC! +1

Answer (score 1):

I also had some time to play around. For my solution there are no limits concerning A being odd or even or larger than 1. Every integer is fine (even 0 works, though it does not make sense).

```
% NxN matrix
N = 7;
A = magic(N);

half = ceil( N/2 );

mask = ones( half );
mask( 1 : half+1 : half*half ) = 0;
mask = [ fliplr( mask ) mask ];
mask = [ mask; flipud( mask ) ];
if( mod(N,2) == 1 )
    mask(half, :) = []
    mask(:, half) = []
end

A( ~mask ) = 0;
A
```

I am first creating a square sub-matrix mask of "quarter" size (half the number of columns and half the number of rows, `ceil()` to get one more in the case N is odd).

Example for `N=7` -> `half=4`.

```
mask =

     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
```

I then set it's diagonal values to zero:

```
mask =

     0     1     1     1
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0
```

Mirror the mask horizontally:

```
mask =

     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

Then mirror it vertically:

```
mask =

     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
```

As `N` is odd we got a redundant row and redundant column that are then removed:

```
mask =

     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
```

The logical not is then used as a mask to select the values in the original matrix that are set to 0.

Probably not as efficient as @Amro's solution, but it works. :D

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

looking at the first left half of the matrix

- in the first row `0` is in the middle column (let's call it `mc`)
- in the second row the `0`is in column `mc-1`
- and so on while the rows increase
- when you reach column 1 the sequence continue but with `mc+1` but the rows decrease

In a similar way for the right half of the matrix

```
n=7
a=randi([20 30],n,n)
% Centre of the matrix
p=ceil(n/2)
% Identify the column sequence
col=[p:-1:1 2:p p+1:n n-1:-1:p]
% Identify the row sequence
row=[1:n n-1:-1:1]
% Transorm the row and column index in linear index
idx=sub2ind(size(a),row,col)
% Set the 0'
a(idx)=0


a =

    22    29    23    27    27    21    23
    29    29    21    27    24    26    24
    30    28    21    27    29    28    25
    28    22    24    20    27    24    25
    23    26    21    20    30    20    29
    26    20    26    23    25    22    25
    21    24    25    25    23    21    30


a =

    22    29    23     0    27    21    23
    29    29     0    27     0    26    24
    30     0    21    27    29     0    25
     0    22    24    20    27    24     0
    23     0    21    20    30     0    29
    26    20     0    23     0    22    25
    21    24    25     0    23    21    30
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Answer (score 1):

Using indexing (only works when `N` is odd):

```
N = 7;

% Random matrix
A = randi(100, N);

idx = [N-1:-2:1; 2:2:N];
A(cumsum([ceil(N/2) idx(:)' idx(end-1:-1:1)])) = 0

A =

    60    77    74     0    54    83     9
     8    48     0    76     0    28    67
     6     0    32    78    83     0    10
     0    27    25     5    11    39     0
    76     0    49    43    67     0    16
    79     7     0    86     0    70    78
    57    28    85     0    81    44    81
```