# How to transform this 2x2 matrix to the 3x3 matrix shown?

Tags: matlab

How to convert the matrix below to the one required in Matlab, I tried using logicals but couldn't make logic:

```
 6     8
10    16
```

required

```
 6     0     8
 0     0     0
10     0    16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code following would work:

```
A=[6 8; 10 16];
B=zeros(3);
B([1,3],[1,3])=A;
B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
B=zeros(3);
B([1,end],[1,end])=A;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are probably what you want, and yet, here's a needlessly complicated way to do the same thing:

```
B = conv2( ones(2), A) .* ~strel('diamond',1).Neighborhood;
```

The [`strel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) function requires the Image Processing Toolbox, so if you don't have it, you can instead use some variations of the solutions to these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36316330/3372061), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33756154/3372061).

Tested on R2018b.